# Update text on a website by an e-mail

Tags: php, html-email, email-attachments, email

My client is a restaurant that needs to change a paragraph section (`<P>`) every day for specials.

There are many people that will be handling it so I have to make it as easy a possible.

I don't think teaching the whole staff how to use a CMS is feasible, so I thought it would be a good idea to make something like an email service, that only updates that bit of text.

So in other words the staff would just have to send an email, and the server would somehow change the text on the HTML page for that day.

Can I do this in PHP code maybe?

I am also open to other ideas to something easy, like a simple login system to just change that bit of text.

Comment: Create a simple page with login and a textfield to update the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend setting the text by e-mail. E-mail is an ugly, UGLY format to process, especially if it is sent by humans on every type of broken e-mail clients. The half of the e-mails will be invalid HTML, the other half will be tabulated unimaginably, the third half will contain signatures and there are so many more halves :)

And explaining the e-mail format you expect to the staff (utf-8 plain text with no signatures, etc...), and how to set it on their Outlook Expresses, Netscape Mails, and web clients you never even heard of, will be just as difficult as explaining a CMS.

What I would recommend is a simple form instead. If you open the form the current text could show up in a text field, and upon posting back the form you save it's contents on the server.

You would need to store this text somewhere. There is very few servers that host web applications without some form of database backends, so I'm pretty sure you have some kind of database to store your text in.

Also the form would need some kind of password protection. The easiest would be IMHO to password protect the folder where your php is. It's not too hard in Apache.

Check this link: http://www.groovypost.com/howto/htaccess-password-protect-apache-website-security/

I'm not familiar with your experience in PHP, but I hope you can make a form to edit a database record. If not, then please use google, there are tons of tutorials on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use imap extension http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php it allows you to read emails from email box. usualy, programmers create keywords that act like commands to script, for example, if title of email is match pattern `UPDATE pageID` then it will process email body as content for this page.
This script will be running with `crontab`, which is scheduler for unix OS. So you can run it every 1 hour for checking new mail.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your client could send an excel sheet and you parse this email attachment on server side with php.

https://code.google.com/p/php-excel/

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a blogging platform to post the latest specials. You could then use PHP to grab the RSS output (last feed item) and populate the website. This would take care of the form, log in and security part. It also gives the client a running history.

(if you want to go this route I can post an rss reader php script to help you out)

Alternatively, if you decide to go the email route, put the text between something like this:

```
<!-- PUT PARAGRAPH HERE -->
Here is today's specials.
<!-- /PUT PARAGRAPH HERE -->
```

Can be anything really, but bookending it with something constant you can search for in the string will help avoid many of the issues mentioned by @SoonDead above. PHP can convert it into something consistent, but you'll need some php knowledge to make it work.